# getting this error "ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model, are m2m fields, or are non-concrete fields: last_login"

Tags: django, django-models

i am trying to login user with otp and after checking the otp when i try to login a user with login method i get  error on this line of my login*otp method -->login(request,user). i also added last*login field but nothing changes it gives same error

Here are my Custom User model:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        mobile_number=request.session['mobile_number']
        print(mobile_number)
        otp=request.POST.get('otp')

        try:
            user_profile=User_Profile.objects.get(Phone=mobile_number)
            print(user_profile.Otp)
            
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request,"Invalid mobile nummber")
            return redirect('login_with_otp')

        if otp!=str(user_profile.Otp):
            print(type(otp))
            print(type(user_profile.Otp))
            print(otp)
            print(user_profile.Otp)
            messages.error(request,"Invalid OTP oh")
            return redirect('login_with_otp')

        user_profile.Otp=None
        user_profile.save()
        print(user_profile.id)
        user_profile = User_Profile.objects.get(Email=user_profile.User_id)
        print("user object : ",type(user_profile))
        print(user_profile)
        login(request,user_profile)
        messages.success(request,"You are now logged in")
        return redirect('home')
```

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, unique=True)
    username= models.CharField(max_length=75)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS= ['username']
```

i did everything but nothing changes error is as it is and also i found that error is caused by this line in models.py of django auth model

```
File "C:\Users\rishi\Desktop\Hosted surginatal\env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 23, in update_last_login
    user.save(update_fields=["last_login"])
```